# Facing null pointer Exception in at RpcMap?

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, gxt

I am trying to read a serialized DTO at server side object from file, i can read it without any exception but after some exception throws when rpc replies to client side

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.RpcMap.size(RpcMap.java:198)
```

what is the issue?

i m using GXT 2.2.5.

here is a server side code

```
public List<ShellCommand> getCommands(String user, String platform)
        throws CVSServiceException {
        readFromFile();
        if(commands.isEmpty())
            return null;
        else
            return commands;
}

private void readFromFile(){
    File readFile = new File(DIR, SHELLCOMMAND);
    if(readFile.exists()){
        try{
            InputStream file = new FileInputStream(readFile);
            InputStream buffer = new BufferedInputStream( file );
            ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream ( buffer );
            try{
                commands = (List<ShellCommand>) input.readObject();
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                input.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

i can read and feel my list `commands` perfactly but then after calling `getcommands()` from client side it throws this error causes my RPC call to fail?

Comment: are `ShellCommand` class is serializable? default constructor in `ShellCommand`??